# find the products which is not order on particular month

Tags: sql, postgresql

i want to find the products which doesnt have orders on particular month

i have here three tables products, productorder, orderitems

```
Products 
id | name |  price 

ProductOrder 
id | total_amount | order_date

OrderItems
id| product_id | order_id
```

this is the query i have tried

```
select * from products p 

left join orderitems oi on oi.product_id = p.id 

left join productorder po on oi.order_id= po.id 

where extract('month' from po.order_date) = 1 

and po.id is null
```

but its giving empyt result.. So how could i find the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like `not exists`:

```
select p.*
from products p
where not exists (select 1
                  from productorder po join
                       orderitems oi
                       on oi.order_id = po.id
                  where oi.product_id = p.id and
                        po.order_date >= '2020-12-01' and
                        po.order_date < '2021-01-01'
                 );
```

Comment: sorry i am not good at sql .. i thought using joins is more efficient than subquery.. so i was looking for a solution which uses joins instead of subquery...Let me ask you one thing why we cant solve this using joins...if you dont mind could you please elaborate...

Comment: @tstudent . . You can solve it using joins (as other answers show).  In most databases, `left join` and `not exists` will have similar performance.  `in` often has worse performance.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. Just use condition `extract('month' from po.order_date) = 1` in the `LEFT JOIN` as follows:

```
select * 
  from products p 
  left join orderitems oi on oi.product_id = p.id 
  left join productorder po on oi.order_id= po.id 
                            and extract('month' from po.order_date) = 1
 where oi.id is null;
```

Also, As mentioned in the answer by Gordon, it is better to use the `dates` rather than `extract` function.

**-- update**

```
select * 
  from products p 
  left join 
    (select oi.product_id 
       from orderitems oi
       join productorder po on oi.order_id= po.id 
                           and extract('month' from po.order_date) = 1) oi
     On p.id = oi.product_id
  where oi.product_id is null;
```

Comment: thanks a lot  @popeye for your support.. i have one query , why "where extract('month' from po.order_date) = 1 and po.id is null " doesnt work 
Also from your answer po.id doesnt works and oi.id is null works . why so..
if you dont mind could you please explain ....

Answer (score 1):

Something like that would work:

```
select * from products p 
where p.id NOT IN (
  select oi.product_id from orderitems oi
  inner join productorder po on oi.order_id= po.id
  where date_part('month', po.order_date) = 1
)
```

You may check a simple example in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6303a/7).

The above will fetch the product ids that did not have any sale in the first month of 2020. This is done by using `NOT IN()...` and by selecting all the product ids that did have sales on that month, in the sub-query.

Comment: which is efficient using join or not in